# Bulk insert not recognizing row terminators

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, bcp

I'm preparing format files to import text-qualified files into sql-server based on [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/02/04/how-to-remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-while-importing-a-data-file/)

Sample of data for import:

```
"1000000"|"1100000"|"2017-02-26 00:00:00"|"CAT1"|"Item from CAT1"
"1000001"|"1100000"|"2017-02-26 00:00:01"|"CAT2"|"Item from CAT2"
"1000002"|"1100001"|"2017-02-26 00:01:02"|"CAT2"|"Item from CAT2"
"1000003"|"1100002"|"2017-02-26 01:02:03"|"CAT3"|"Item from CAT3"
```

My format file:

```
13.0
6
1       SQLCHAR             0       0       "\""        0     FIRST_QUOTE                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLINT              0       4       "\"|\""     1     transaction_id                  ""
3       SQLINT              1       4       "\"|\""     2     user_id                         ""
4       SQLDATETIME         0       8       "\"|\""     3     create_date                     ""
5       SQLCHAR             2       10      "\"|\""     4     category                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             2       50      "\"\r\n"    5     item                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Which results in:

> The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 6. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.

I'm fairly certain that file contains \r\n (Checked with Hex editor shows 0x0d,0x0a), although ignoring text qualifiers and format file i was able to import it manually only with

```
Bulk insert <table_name> from '\\path\to\file' with (fieldterminator='|', rowterminator='\n')
```

Comment: just use `\n`, not `\r\n`.  The former is 'carriage return, line feed ' (aka, CRLF).  The latter is 'carriage return, carriage return, line feed' (CRCRLF).  Not sure if that actually fixes the problem, though. (FYI, `x0dx0a` is CRLF, so maybe your reported file format is incorrect and the actual one is fine?)

Comment: Sorry if you already checked this, but, is there a chance that the length of `item` exceeds 50 ?

Comment: @SqlZim Yes, i imported it though a wizard and it went though fine. Also i'm fairly certain source field in another database is also varchar(50)

Comment: @ps2goat makes sense. I did not realize that \n also contains CR part. However, i did try to change last delimiter to both "\"\n" and "\n" (ignoring last text qualifier), and got same error.

Comment: you are only showing us 5 columns, but the error references a sixth... it helps us help you if you give us all the info you have.

Comment: @ps2goat That's everything that is in there, first column is dummy to parse out first qualifier in a line. So source file contain 6 columns and output contains 5, with first one being ignored (due to 0 length in format file first column will be ignored)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried poking at your format file, but it just confirmed that I am not any good with that version of the format file.

Switching over to an xml format file was easy enough though.

cat.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
<FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"'     COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"|"'   COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"|"'   COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"|"'   COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"|"'   COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"\r\n' COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
</RECORD>
<ROW>
<COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="transaction_id" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
<COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="user_id" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
<COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="create_date" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
<COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="category" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
<COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="item" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
</ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

sql:

```
bulk insert dbo.cat
   from 'c:\cat.txt'
   with (
      formatfile = 'c:\cat.xml'
    , firstrow   = 1
  );
```

results:

[image]

input file, showing row terminator in notepad++:

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. So it's probably was an issue with some funky formatting within format file itself. Thanks.

Comment: Very smart of you mate to use notepad++ to identify the rowterminator. You are my hero!